# How to use both IN condition and NOT IN same query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle I need a query it from IN condition and exclude the NOT IN condition for my dynamic query creation.

Example:

```
Select *  
from tbl_namw 
where number in (1,2,3,4,5,6) 
and number not in select number from tbl_number where number in (2,3)
```

In the above query is not excluding the value.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: If you dont want it then Why include it in `IN` clause ?

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.

Comment: My requirement is first query i give all the value and the second query i give exclude value

Comment: I gave only sample for yours reference

Comment: If you dont want it then Why include it in IN clause ? Reason for using IN condition is I am getting the value my dynamically. This is query i am going to implement for auomation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like :

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CITY IN ('Paris','London','Lille','Mumbai')
 AND CITY NOT IN ('Lille','London');
```

?

instead of your query which translates as this :

```
  SELECT * FROM Users WHERE City IN ('Paris','London','Lille') AND CITY
NOT IN (SELECT CITY FROM Users WHERE CITY IN ('Lille','London'));
```

They both give the same output you need , the first one is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you've outlined in your post but your syntax is wrong. You need parenthesis around the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_namw
 WHERE number IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
   AND number NOT IN ( SELECT number FROM tbl_number WHERE number IN (2,3) );
```

I'm not sure I really understand the purpose of using a subquery, however. Why not just do the following, with the understanding that the numbers in the `IN` clause are dynamic, and the numbers in the `NOT IN` are the ones you want to exclude?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_namw
 WHERE number IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) -- dynamic list
   AND number NOT IN (2,3);
```